# Ubuntu cron not executing, but works fine on command line

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron, backup

I have a backup cron job that is supposed to run once a week. It works perfectly fine when I execute it on the command line, but it never executes in cron. My other cron tasks execute without issue. I assume it must have something to do with my options or incorrect syntax. Here is the cron entry in question:

```
10 10 * * 0 php ~/v2/symfony/symfony cc; tar -czf ~/backups/schroeder/v2/v2_site_backup_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M`.tgz ~/v2/symfony | tee -a ~/log/weekly_backup.log
```

**SOLUTION**
Turns out I needed to escape the % when inputting it my cron list. So the command that works is:

```
10 10 * * 0 php ~/v2/symfony/symfony cc; tar -czf ~/backups/schroeder/v2/v2_site_backup_`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M`.tgz ~/v2/symfony | tee -a ~/log/weekly_backup.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crontab` has a very small environment, so you have to indicate full paths.

```
10 10 * * 0 /path/of/php /home/your_user/v2/symfony/symfony cc; tar -czf /home/your_user/backups/schroeder/v2/v2_site_backup_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M`.tgz /home/your_user/v2/symfony | tee -a /home/your_user/log/weekly_backup.log
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
10 10 * * 0 php ~/v2/symfony/symfony cc; tar -czf ~/backups/schroeder/v2/v2_site_backup_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M`.tgz ~/v2/symfony | tee -a ~/log/weekly_backup.log
```

That is, change all `~` for `/home/your_user/`.

Also! Escape each `%` as read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/33550/using-crontab-to-tar-a-directory-at-a-regular-interval/33553#33553):

```
date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M
```

has to be

```
date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to change the other 2 '~' references as well?  If not, why?  **edit: nevermind I missed the 'all ~' in your post. Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately no. The log doesn't spit anything out either. Here's another task we run daily that works perfectly fine: {5 3 * * * php ~/v2/symfony/symfony dbBackup --verbose=true | tee -a ~/v2/symfony/log/db_backup.log
}

Comment: Ops now I see I had two asterisks together and also kept one `~`. What if you execute this exact command in your command line?

Comment: If i execute the command I initially posted it works and if I use the one you posted substituting my user it works as well. Neither work via cron.

Comment: I also tried substituting the shortcut 'backups' directory with the actual path and that does not work either.

Comment: Are you executing the script with the same user that user the crontab?

Comment: Yes. All of the cron jobs are executed under the same user. This is the same user that I am using to execute on the command line.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with -czf? I read somewhere that the dash and option order could have some effect.

Comment: Oh now I see, you need to escape the `%` in `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M`. Read in http://serverfault.com/a/33553/200076